# What will happen to background process after restarting the IOS device . Will it be Suspended?

Tags: ios7, background, xcode5

What will happen to background process after restarting the device. Will it be Suspended?

Answer (score 0):

Yes... the device is restarted so all is reseted.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to resume the background process of app?